# Excel macro to select next/previous file in folder

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a macro that imports a txt file and displays some XY co-ordinates in a scatter graph. I'd like to be able choose a folder then hit next/back to view the other files in the folder rather than select each file individually.

This is the macro, each time I select the file, it pastes the XY values into the relevant place on the sheet (I have to do it this way to pick out the columns I need from the source data).  The tool is useful but would be 10x better if I could hit one button to see the next file as I often have 30+ files to check

```
Public Sub TxtToCol()
'Step1: delete existing contents
Columns("A:j").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select

'Updated to include ImportText macro into main code

    Dim textFileNum, rowNum, colNum As Integer
    Dim textFileLocation, textDelimiter, textData As String
    Dim tArray() As String
    Dim sArray() As String
    textFileLocation = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    'If no file selected stop macro
    If textFileLocation = False Then Exit Sub
    textDelimiter = ","
    textFileNum = FreeFile

    Open textFileLocation For Input As textFileNum
    textData = Input(LOF(textFileNum), textFileNum)
    Close textFileNum
    tArray() = Split(textData, vbLf)
    For rowNum = LBound(tArray) To UBound(tArray) - 1
        If Len(Trim(tArray(rowNum))) <> 0 Then
            sArray = Split(tArray(rowNum), textDelimiter)
            For colNum = LBound(sArray) To UBound(sArray)
                ActiveSheet.Cells(rowNum + 1, colNum + 1) = sArray(colNum)
            Next colNum
        End If
    Next rowNum
    'MsgBox "Data Imported Successfully", vbInformation

    'Find XY co-ordinates, text to columns with 'space' delimiter, select full range then cut and paste into new area
    Cells.Find(What:="+00.000", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, OtherChar _
        :="=", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("D9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Now co-ords are moved, remaining data can be delimited by '='
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="=", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    'Add updated cant formula to avoid Vlookup error
    Range("U5").Formula = (Range("E9") - Range("E10")) * 1000
    'Return to cell A1
    Range("A1").Select
    'MsgBox "Data Imported Successfully", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Based on your tags, this is for a Mac?

Comment: "next" in any particular order?

Comment: The default should be the first file in the folder then select next or back either a message of eg 'no more files' when you reach the first or last file